# Supremum norm of a function whose Fourier transform is in weighted $L_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that I have a positive function $w(x)>0$ and it defines a weighted $L^w_2$-space by
$$
L^w_2 = \{f:{\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb C}\mid \int_{-\infty}^\infty w(x)|f(x)|^2dx<\infty\}
$$
with norm
$$
\|f\|_{L^w_2} = \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty w(x)|f(x)|^2dx}
$$
Let $\Omega = [a,b]$ some finite interval. How can I bound
$$
\sup_{\|\mathcal{F}[f]\|_{L^w_2}\leq 1, \|f\|_{L_2([a,b])}\leq 1}\|f\|_{L_\infty([a,b])}
$$
in terms of $w(x)$? Here $\mathcal{F}[f]$ is Fourier transform of $f$.

Answer (score 4):

The conclusion depends on the growth of the weight and does not hold for any weight.

For example let $w(x)\equiv 1$ and $$f_0(x)=\begin{cases}x^{-1/4}& 0<x<1/4\\ 0& {\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ Then $\|\mathcal{F}[f_0]\|_2=\|f_0\|_2=1,$ but the function $f_0$ is unbounded on the interval $[0,1/4].$

If the weight has sufficient growth at infinity the conclusion is valid. For example
let $w(x)=1+x^2.$ Then the function $\mathcal{F}[f]$ is absolutely integrable as by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get
$$\displaylines{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\mathcal{F}[f](x)|\,dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\mathcal{F}[f](x)|w(x)^{1/2}\,w(x)^{-1/2}\,dx \\ \le \pi^{1/2}\,\|\mathcal{F}[f]\|_{L_2^w}}$$ By the Fourier inversion formula we get that $f$ is continuous and
$$f(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{F}[f](x)\,e^{2\pi itx}\,dx$$ Therefore $$\|f\|_\infty\le \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\mathcal{F}[f](x)|\,dx\le \pi^{1/2}\,\|\mathcal{F}[f]\|_{L_2^w}$$
By the same reasoning if $w(x)^{-1}$ is integrable then $$\|f\|_\infty\le \|w^{-1}\|_1^{1/2}\|\,\|\mathcal{F}[f]\|_{L_2^w}$$

Comment: Yes, of course it is unbounded in general. The question is when it is bounded? Are there any non-trivial bounds in terms of $w$?

Comment: I am a bit confused. The $f$ of the first part of your post is not the same $f$ as the second part, is that it?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It is not the same. The second part is valid for all $f.$ I have changed $f$ to $f_0$ in the first part.

Comment: Great! I am surprised that $\|f\|_{L_2([a,b])}<1$ is not even needed.

Comment: Actually the estimate of $\|f\|_2$ is hidden in $\|\mathcal{F}[f]\|_{L_2^w}$ if $w(x)\ge 1,$ like in the example $w(x)=x^2+1.$ In that case $\|\mathcal{F}[f]\|_{L_2^w}\ge \|\mathcal{F}[f]\|_{L_2}= \|f\|_{L_2}.$